# Can a mixed state be represented on a Bloch sphere?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

I have a hard time getting the exact difference between concepts of superposed and mixed states. Is it possible to represent the second one on the Bloch sphere, to show the main difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A pure, superposed, state corresponds to a point on the surface of the sphere. A mixed state corresponds to a point *inside* the sphere. The closer to the centre, the more mixed the state is.